# Why does my SQL statement not find a match with the WHERE statement below?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, where-clause

I'm attempting to pull data from my MS Access database via an Excel SQL statement.  It does NOT give me any errors, however it also does not pull the data I'm searching for.

If `items(u, 1)` is text (ex. 308-203BL), then it works perfectly.

I've tried both comparing them as text and as numerical, but neither way find any matches when `items(u, 1)` is 19310.

This compares it as text...

```vb
LEFT(Item," & Len(items(u, 1)) & ") = '" & items(u, 1) & "'"
```

this compares it as numerical...

```vb
VAL(LEFT(Item," & Len(items(u, 1))) & ") = " & items(u, 1)
```

I have verified that there are records in the DB that match the given criteria.

`items()` is an array populated from a 1 column table on the sheet by `items = Range("Items").Value`[image: Table Snip].
Using these two SKU's as examples, the first working, the second not, the array would be as follows.  [image: Pic of populated array].
SKU by SKU, they're fed into the SQL as below.

With the input in the example, the output I receive is an array populated only the sales for the second item.  The order I put the SKU's in the table doesn't change that result. I have tested it with multiple SKU's, and no matter how many I use, it returns the proper information, with the exception of not returning any results for any numerical SKU's.

The field for `Item` in the DB is a short text, which is why I used `'" & items(u, 1) & "'"` to convert the SKU to text when I was trying to match it as text, and `Val()` to convert the field to a value when trying to match it as a number.  Both gave me 0 record counts in the function, but did not give me a data type error.

Below is the portion of my code which determines the SQL string, and a bit afterwords which basically stuffs it into a UDF which pulls the info from the DB and puts it into an array for me.  Aside from not finding a match when `items(u,1)` is numerical, it works perfectly.

```vb
DBString = "SELECT Invoice, Line, Inv_Date, Sales_Order, SOLine, SO_Date, CustID, Item, Part_Description, Ship_Qty, Price, Ext_Sales FROM `" & Year(tabledate) & "-" & Format(tabledate, "mm") & "` WHERE Inv_Date BETWEEN #" & Sdate & "# AND #" & Edate & "# AND LEFT(Item," & Len(items(u, 1)) & ") = '" & items(u, 1) & "'"
SalesHolder = PullFromDB(DBString, SGMDB)
```

I've also tried the below code instead, to force it to compare as a number instead of text, which also doesn't give me any errors, but doesn't find a match.

```vb
DBString = "SELECT Invoice, Line, Inv_Date, Sales_Order, SOLine, SO_Date, CustID, Item, Part_Description, Ship_Qty, Price, Ext_Sales FROM `" & Year(tabledate) & "-" & Format(tabledate, "mm") & "` WHERE Inv_Date BETWEEN #" & Sdate & "# AND #" & Edate & "# AND VAL(LEFT(Item," & Len(items(u, 1))) & ") = " & items(u, 1)
SalesHolder = PullFromDB(DBString, SGMDB)
```

Below is the UDF itself which pulls the info from the DB. It works quite nicely.

```vb
Function PullFromDB(DBStr As String, DBLoc As String) As Variant
    Dim TheDB As Recordset, DBHolder() As Variant

    Set TheDB = OpenDatabase(DBLoc).OpenRecordset(DBStr)
    If TheDB.RecordCount = 0 Then GoTo theexit

    TheDB.MoveLast
    TheDB.MoveFirst

    ReDim DBHolder(0 To TheDB.RecordCount, 1 To TheDB.Fields.Count) As Variant

    For k = 1 To UBound(DBHolder, 2)
        TheDB.MoveFirst
        For j = 0 To UBound(DBHolder)
            If j = 0 Then
                DBHolder(j, k) = TheDB.Fields(k - 1).Name
            Else
                DBHolder(j, k) = TheDB.Fields(k - 1).Value
                TheDB.MoveNext
            End If
         Next j
    Next k

theexit:
    TheDB.Close
    Set TheDB = Nothing
    PullFromDB = DBHolder

On Error GoTo -1
End Function
```

The expected result is to populate the array SalesHolder with the information that matches the criteria.

What am I missing?  I'm going blind trying to find it.

Comment: What is contained in *items(u, 1)*? Please show. You also *tell* us criteria is not met but do not *show* us any data. What actually happens? No results are returned?

Comment: Hi. In the db your field is text or numerical?

Comment: @Parfait I've updated my question with the question you've requested.

Comment: @LuisCurado I've updated my post with the answer.

Comment: Why do you need Left()? Data in table is not exactly same as from Excel? Could try opposite, make sure number is read as string: `CStr(Item)`. Really shouldn't be necessary if field is text type, but try it anyway.

Comment: @June7 `Left()` is so that the user can enter partial SKU's and still return results, which is useful for items with multiple colors, since only the suffix differs between them.  I actually had `CStr(Item)` initially but removed it after having researched that it wasn't necessary; it gave me the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses to this, it turns out I was completely hunting for the wrong problem.  The code I posted was actually correct, the issue was with the format of `Inv_Date` field in the DB.  I had mistakenly entered the last couple of months as text instead of date, so the `WHERE Inv_Date BETWEEN #" & Sdate & "# AND #" & Edate & "#` portion of my SQL didn't match anything.

I hadn't identified that this was the issue earlier due to the timing of the sales of the SKU's themselves, which was purely coincidence.  When I expanded the dates range, I found that it did return results for the numerical SKU, but both numerical and text SKU's cut off two months ago.

Thank you again!